# Display articles with a different template in the home page | Solved |

Tags: php, posts, loop, templates, query

I am creating a theme for my site. I would like to display the last 5 articles on the home page but with a different display for the first articles.
So I created this code that I try to tweak but impossible to display the first article with the first template and the 4 others with the second template. I don't know if it's possible to do it the way I want to do it, but this way seems to be the easiest

My code :

```
<?php
  $query = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5
  ];
  $query = new WP_Query($query);
  while ($query->have_posts()) : {
    $query->the_post();
    if($query === 1) :
      get_template_part('loops/acc-cards');
    else() :
      get_template_part('loops/cards');
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, it missed an endwhile;

```
 <?php
  $query = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5
  );
  $query = new WP_Query($query);
  while ($query->have_posts()) : 
    $query->the_post();
    if($query->current_post === 0) :
      get_template_part('mining-inc/loops/acc-cards');
    else :
      get_template_part('loops/cards');
    endif;
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it looks like you just need to set an iteration variable (usually abbreviated `$i`), like this:

```
<?php
$i = 0; // This sets your variable
$query = [
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 5
];

$query = new WP_Query($query);
  while ($query->have_posts()) : {
    $query->the_post();
    if($i == 0) :
      get_template_part('loops/acc-cards');
    else() :
      get_template_part('loops/cards');
  }
$i++ // This iterates the iteration variable $i
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have php errors that appear:
It tells me that the () in else are too many. I remove them a new error appears: they are the {} of the while which appear in error syntax. I remove them I have the wp_reset_data in error syntax ...

Comment: If this is the error you're receiving (` Fatal error: Uncaught Error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in \wp-content\themes\picostrap5\front-page.php`) it just means that you probably forgot to close an if statement or something like that.

Comment: With an endif and the () on the else I only have the last error : <?php
  $query = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5
  ];
  $query = new WP_Query($query);
  while ($query->have_posts()) : {
    $query->the_post();
    if($query->current_post === 0) :
      get_template_part('mining-inc/loops/acc-cards');
    else:
      get_template_part('mining-inc/loops/cards');
    endif;
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>

Comment: I don't see the last error. Can you put it between ticks so it looks like `this`?

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: syntax error, unexpected end of file
in \themes\picostrap5\front-page.php on line 89

Pile d’appel :

    require_once()
    wp-blog-header.php:19
    require()
    index.php:17[](null)`

Answer (score 0):

The proper day to do it in WordPress is to use the [`current_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties) value instead of setting your own variable like `$i`. `current_post` is the index of the current post in a loop that starts with 0.

```
<?php
  $query = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5
  );
  $query = new WP_Query($query);
  while ($query->have_posts()) :
    $query->the_post();
    if($query->current_post === 0) :
      get_template_part('loops/acc-cards');
    else:
      get_template_part('loops/cards');
    endif;
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Same problem as with the code above I have php errors that appear: It tells me that the () of the else are too much. I remove them a new error appears: they are the {} of the while that appear in error syntax. 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: syntax error, unexpected end of file
in \wp-content\themes\picostrap5\front-page.php on line 70

Pile d’appel :

    require_once()
    wp-blog-header.php:19
    require()
    index.php:17

Comment: This code by itself does not have any errors. The error is most likely located somewhere else in your front-page.php file which is impossible to tell without seeing the actual code since all themes are different.

Comment: I remove the code I have no more errors and vs code does not detect any either. I have tried with classic wordpress themes and I have the same errors

Comment: I dig the `current_post` correction!

Comment: With an endif and the () on the else I only have the last error :/

Comment: @Outkax Fixed the code. try it now.

Comment: Thank you I had also seen the missing endwhile the next morning. Some rest is good sometimes x)